# how to implement any genetic ant finding food in Push,Clojush,Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop, clojure-contrib, clojure-core.logic

I am trying to use Push,Clojush,Clojure to implement an ant finding food in a 2d map, but I am not sure how to represent map? Could someone give me a example? Thank you.

Comment: [Go to the Clojush page at GitHub](https://github.com/lspector/Clojush) and read the QuickStart section. You'll need to have Clojure and Leiningen installed on your machine. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a whole implementation of an ant simulation in Clojure at https://github.com/juliangamble/clojure-ants-simulation

To your specific question, it uses a vector of vectors: 
https://github.com/juliangamble/clojure-ants-simulation/blob/master/src/ants.clj#L36

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I want to use push, which is a "feature" in Clojure. And I do not know how to do it.

Comment: @SwordW If you don't know how to do it with push, then either you don't understand it or you don't understand your problem, or you understand either, or you understand both and it's just not the right way to do it.